# How can I setup my computer for windows application development environment with Qt 3.3.0?

Tags: c++, qt

Today I am interested to develop some windows applications and installed Qt 3.3.0 also. I choose Qt Widgets Application and leave the create in location to be default i.e. C:\Users\ComputerName\Documents I don't checked on Use as default project location checkbox and click on next button. Now here in Kits tab it said to **No valid kits found** and next button is disabled. I don't have installed anything else than Qt. So how can I setup my computer for windows application development environment with Qt 3.3.0 ?

Comment: I think you have only installled Qt Creator and by Qt 3.3.0 you mean Qt Creator 3.3.0. Is it true? The current version of Qt is 5.4.0. You should install Qt, a C++ compiler, a debugger and Qt Creator.

Comment: Which should I download Qt 5.4.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, 704 MB) or Qt 5.4.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, OpenGL, 694 MB) or Qt 5.4.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 643 MB) or Qt 5.4.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 625 MB) or Qt 5.4.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.1, 852 MB) ?

Comment: You should download the one that is compatible with your c++ compiler. For example if you have installed VS2013, just download  `Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, 704 MB)`.

Comment: Use can use visual studio to compile your code. before that you should have Qt compiled code for windows(Build using visual studio). But in visual studio we will get drag and drop functionality...

Answer (score 0):

In Tools->Options "Build&Run" section you need to make sure that at least one kit is defined. To do that you also need to have at least one "Qt version" and "Compiler" defined in your QtCreator. Perhaps you've installed only the IDE without mingw?

Comment: I have only installed Qt 3.3.0 nothing else

Comment: Find and installer that contains also the compiler, not only QtCreator. It will set up kits automatically and it should work.

Comment: Does Qt 5.4.0 have contained the compiler also ?

Comment: Yes, if you choose an appropriate version. "Qt 5.4.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.1, 852 MB)" should do the trick for you.

Comment: The package mentioned above contains the compiler. Install it and look at the directories structure.
[Qt]\Tools\mingw491_32\bin - compiler  
[Qt]\5.4\mingw491_32\bin - Qt libs and tools

Comment: @encds I think Nejat's point is: the edition name in the parentheses means the Qt library was compiled by that compiler, and **it doesn't mean that you are supposed to get the corresponding compiler from the package.** The reason why MinGW is contained is just because *it's free*. This point should be emphasized to avoid further misunderstanding for the OP is quite new to Qt. In OP's case, it's more recommended to choose Qt with MSVC compiler to develop Windows application.